# Failing to build a 'queue-like' structure - problems with struct declarations?

Tags: c, struct

Hey guys. This is a very simple question, I'm sure, but I'm getting myself tangled up in C references/pointers as per usual. I am trying to build a... sort-of-queue, using a sort-of-linked list. Basically, I have a struct which has contents and a pointer to the next element. I also have a pointer to the first and last elements. I then have a loop that will be building the 'sort-of-queue'. My problem is that either my logic is failing and I'm not initialising the queue right, or my knowledge of C structs is failing (which is very probable) and I'm ending up just creating one struct and constantly referring to it.

My test code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct test {
    int contents;
    struct test *next;
};

main() {

    struct test *first = NULL;
    struct test *last = NULL;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        struct test tmp;
        if (first == NULL) {
            first = &tmp;
            last = &tmp;
        } else {
            last->next = &tmp;
            last = &tmp;
        }
        tmp.x = i;
        tmp.next = NULL;
    }

    while (first != NULL) {
        printf("%d\n", first->x);
        first = first->next;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Running this, I get the output that first seems to point to a test struct that has the value of '1' as it's 'x' variable - so not the initial one like I intended. So, am I failing at logic here, or am I failing at understanding how to declare new separate structs in a loop? Or maybe both? I'm very tired... >_<.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you are taking the address of a temporary variable, `tmp`, and assigning it to a pointer which lives much longer than teh temporary, `first` and `last`.  After every iteration of the loop the temporary is gone and continuing to access it via `first` and `last` results in undefined behavior.

You need to create a value on the heap in order to build up the list like so (error checking omitted for brevity)

```
struct test* tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
```

Later though you'll need to go through and `free` all of the allocated nodes.

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much. Spent a long time in C++ world, where I was told over and over not to grab memory because it is death... Thanks for that.